# Loop through sub-folders with Python on Mac to check if file exists, open, copy, paste then close file

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder, with numerous (~200) sub-folders on my Mac desktop.

Some (but not all) sub-folders contain a csv file named "sample.csv".

Further, I have a "aggregate.csv" file where I would like to copy the 2nd column of each "sample.csv" data into.

```
Structure:

"/Desktop/folder"
"/Desktop/folder/aggregate.csv"

"/Desktop/folder/sub-folder"
"/Desktop/folder/sub-folder/sample.csv"
```

Using Python, how can I loop though each sub-folder, check if "sample.csv" exists, open it, copy the 2nd column, paste this column into the "aggregate.csv" file, close "sample.csv", then move on to the next sub-folder?

In "aggregate.csv", the copied data should increment to the right, so it doesn't overwrite the previous "sample.csv" data that has just been pasted.

My computer is opening the CSV files with Excel, that's why I refer to the "2nd column".

Many thanks

Comment: How many are there likely to be? A few tens, hundreds, millions? Do you really want to write Python if it can be done in the shell in a couple of lines?

Comment: When you say "total.csv", did you mean to say "aggregate.csv"?

Comment: @ Rusty - you are right. that's a typo. my apologies. I have updated the question to correct for this.

Comment: @ Mark - there is up to 200 tops. Yes Python is my preference as I need to repeat this task multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cd ~

$ more aggregate.csv
X
X
X
X
X
X

$ more ./Desktop/folder/sub-folder/sample.csv
A,1
A,2
A,3
A,4
A,5

$ more ./Desktop/folder/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder/sample.csv
B,6
B,7
B,8
B,9

$ more ./Desktop/folder/sub-folder2/sample.csv
C,10
C,11
C,12
C,13
C,14
C,15
C,16

$ more ./Desktop/folder/sub-folder3/sub-sub-folder/sample.csv
D,17
D,18
D,19

$ python3 aggregate_samples.py ./Desktop
./Desktop/folder/sub-folder/sample.csv
./Desktop/folder/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder/sample.csv
./Desktop/folder/sub-folder2/sample.csv
./Desktop/folder/sub-folder3/sub-sub-folder/sample.csv

$ cat aggregate.csv

X,1,6,10,17
X,2,7,11,18
X,3,8,12,19
X,4,9,13,
X,5,,14,
X,,,15,
,,,16,
```

Here is the code that accomplishes this.  The key technologies you need: `os.walk()` to recursively search the folders, the `csv` module to read in the `sample.csv` files (and get the 2nd column), lists to accumulate the samples, and `csv` again to write out the result.  I assumed your `sample.csv` files will be different lengths, and so the code handles that (by pre-allocating a sparse matrix).

This assumes your dataset is small enough to fit into memory.  If not, then more work needs to be done.

```py
# aggregate_samples.py
import os
import sys
import argparse
import csv

def main(options):
    columns = []

    try:
        # Load in aggregate.csv, if there is one.
        with open('aggregate.csv') as f:
            column = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
            columns.append(column)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Doesn't exist; create it later.
        pass

    longest_sample = 0
    for d, subdirs, files in os.walk(options.directory):
        subdirs.sort()
        for filename in files:

            if filename == 'sample.csv':
                file_path = os.path.join(d, filename)
                print(file_path)

                samples = []
                with open(file_path) as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
                    # Get the 2nd column.
                    for sample in reader:
                        samples.append(sample[1])
                longest_sample = max(longest_sample, len(samples))
                columns.append(samples)

    # Pre-fill a transpose matrix according to number of columns
    # and longest colum.
    a = [ [ '' for i in columns ] for j in range(longest_sample) ]

    # Move samples into matrix, transposing as you go.
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        for j in range(len(columns[i])):
            a[j][i] = columns[i][j]

    # Output matrix as CSV.
    with open('aggregate.csv', 'w+') as aggregate:
        writer = csv.writer(aggregate, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(a)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'directory',
        help='Directory path.')
    options = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(main(options))
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! Two follow up questions if I may. To get this to run in Terminal I had to provide the folder directory. How could I tweak this code to provide a hardcoded directory path instead, so that I can run this script direct from within my Atom editor instead of Terminal? Secondly, the first column of  the "aggregate.csv" file contains text that is being overwritten. Is it possible to get the data to start from the 2nd column? I am still learning python and your answer above is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: You don't want to hard code the directory.  Instead, you can provide the directory as a program argument within atom.  I'm using the script package to run the script from within atom.  I don't know of that's what you're using, but "script" seems like a pretty standard way to do it in atom.  I've never used atom before today.  I'll put some screenshots below showing how I set the Program Argument.

Comment: I updated the answer to add to the aggregate.csv file, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the info you need about the `script` package [here](https://atom.io/packages/script).

Here is how to set the Program argument, using Packages->Script->Configure Script:

[image: Packages->Script->Configure Script]

[image]